# Python (tensorflow) - Dropout Regularization accuracy results

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to complete a code for a classification problem (images classification) in python environment. I built a 5 layers NN with a defined number of neurons, using the gradient descent optimizer from tensorflow library. The first 'complete' code brought to an high level of accuracy, but since an overfitting problem had shown, I just decided to introduce a procedure of dropout regularization. At the end of the first run everything appeared as good,  with a *Train Accuracy:1.0* and a *Test Accuracy:0.9606* after training the model over 1000 iterations. Few seconds later, I decided to re-ran the code, and as you can see by the following two images, something went wrong. [Prediction accuracy through dropout regularization - FAIL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3bTm.png) , [Cost function through dropout regularization - FAIL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWXEO.png) .The simulation stopped before of the last defined iteration without giving me any output warning!  Running the same code, how can it be possible? Has anyone had this kind of problem before? Is it a problem of the cross entropy function computation or how can a NN accuracy decay to zero from such an high accuracy level instantaneously?

Comment: can you share your code here for review?

Comment: posted the code!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code. It is based on the mnist dataset used for digit classification problems. Here as it follows:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

Xflatten=tf.reshape(X, [-1, 784])

Y1f=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(Xflatten,W1) + b1)
Y1=tf.nn.dropout(Y1f,pkeep)

Y2f=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(Y1,W2) + b2)
Y2=tf.nn.dropout(Y2f,pkeep)

Y3f=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(Y2,W3) + b3)
Y3=tf.nn.dropout(Y3f,pkeep)

Y4f=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(Y3,W4) + b4)
Y4=tf.nn.dropout(Y4f,pkeep)

Y=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(Y4,W5) + b5)

Y_=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10]) #Y_ stands for the labels representing the digits; "one-hot" encoded

cross_entropy= -tf.reduce_sum(Y_ * tf.log(Y)) #tf.reduce_sum() computes the summation of the required elements for the cross entropy computation

is_correct=tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y,1),tf.argmax(Y_,1)) #tf.argmax() allows to make the "one-hot" decoding
accuracy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(is_correct, tf.float32)) 

optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)train_step=optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy) 

sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

iterations_num=1000 
xaxis=np.arange(iterations_num) 
num_minibatches = int(50000 / minibatch_size) cost_train=[]
accuracy_train=[]
cost_test=[]
accuracy_test=[]

for i in range(iterations_num):

    #load batch of images and correct answers
    batch_X, batch_Y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    train_data={Xflatten: batch_X, Y_: batch_Y}

    #train
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=train_data)

    #success?
    a_train,c_train=sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy], feed_dict=train_data)
    cost_train.append(c_train)
    accuracy_train.append(a_train)

    #success on test data?
    test_data={Xflatten: mnist.test.images, Y_: mnist.test.labels}
    a_test,c_test=sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy], feed_dict=test_data)
    cost_test.append(c_test)
    accuracy_test.append(a_test)

plt.plot(xaxis,cost_train,'b',xaxis,cost_test,'r')

plt.ylabel('cost with dropout regularization')

plt.xlabel('iterations')

plt.title("Learning rate =" + str(learning_rate))

plt.show()

plt.plot(xaxis,accuracy_train,'b',xaxis,accuracy_test,'r')

plt.ylabel('accuracy with dropout regularization')

plt.xlabel('iterations')

plt.title("Learning rate =" + str(learning_rate))

plt.show()

print ("Train Accuracy:" + str(a_train))
print ("Test Accuracy:" + str(a_test))   

sess.close()
```